# typemapping exceptions to java with SWIG, still not caught

Tags: java, c++, swig

I'm trying to use SWIG to wrap some C++ code into java. The code works generally, now I am working on error handling. The C++ code throws a couple types of exceptions. I've gone through all the C++ code and added throw(...) to the function headings, and added this to my SWIG .i file:

```
%include "exception.i"
%typemap(throws, throws="java.io.IOException") std::ios_base::failure {
  jclass excep = jenv->FindClass("java/io/IOException");
  if (excep)
    jenv->ThrowNew(excep, $1.what());
  return $null;
}
%typemap(javabase) std::ios_base::failure "java.lang.Exception";
%typemap(throws, throws="java.lang.IllegalArgumentException") std::invalid_argument {
  jclass excep = jenv->FindClass("java/lang/IllegalArgumentException");
  if (excep)
    jenv->ThrowNew(excep, $1.what());
  return $null;
}
%typemap(javabase) std::invalid_argument "java.lang.Exception";
```

When I look at the generated java files, they all seem to be done correctly, i.e. functions that should throw an exception in java are specified as such with throws ... However, when I run the code and execute a command that generates an exception in the C++ side, it isn't caught by the wrapper and I get:

```
libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception
Abort trap: 6
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I figured this out. It was my fault, of course. For some reason in the C++ code I had decided to throw exceptions via pointer, i.e. `throw new ...` when I should have thrown by reference with `throw ...` as the SWIG code was expecting. Changed that and it is now working as expected.